# How to use webpack in Symfony Bundles

Tags: webpack, symfony4

i configured webpack to create my bundle vue files.
These files are located in `mybundle/src/Resources/public/build/`

my webpack output path looks like this:

```
Encore
  .setOutputPath('src/Resources/public/build/')
  .setPublicPath('/build/')
  .addEntry('einsatz', './assets/vue/views/einsatz/index.js')
```

Now the twig function {{ encore_entry_script_tags('einsatz') }} results in an error because this entry doesnt exists in the main App entrypoints.json. How i can tell twig to look in my bundle folder for the correct entrypoints.json?

Thx for your help.

Comment: What is called your Bundle here? Is this a pre-flex structure or is it a *vendor* bundle?

Comment: the bundle is used as vendor bundle in production. `vendor/me/mybundle/src/...`